# How to select on which monitor YouTube fullscreens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash

I have a dual monitor set-up. When I'm on YouTube, and I click the fullscreen icon, the fullscreen automatically goes to the second monitor. How do I get it to go fullscreen on my main monitor?

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this! Had this problem too and because of that could't really watch the video. +1

Answer (score 8):

The only successful workaround that I have found so far is an extension for Chrome:

[**Multiple Monitor Full Screen**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdnjdibmddfgbdohgacjakddhncfhpcf)

It maximises the Youtube video to the Chrome window which you can then Fullscreen on which ever monitor you like.

You should be aware of a small exiting from full-screen [bug](http://code.google.com/p/full-screen/issues/detail?id=6&can=1) that affects Chrome on Ubuntu. Flash swallows the F11 key command so use Ctrl-Tab to switch to a non-flash tab and use F11 from there.

Comment: How can I choose on which monitor the fullscreen shows up?

Comment: You are fullscreening the Chrome window not the video so which ever one the Chrome window is positioned in...

Comment: This only worked for youtube videos here (though I didn't try vimeo). Any other videos I tried didn't work.
MaximizeFlash worked.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is using the [**MaximizeFlash** plugin for Chrome](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljjmflmcnaigbhnheldbdbplkbhngnl). It detects any flash in the page and you can make them fullscreen. To get rid of toolbar up just hit f11. You dont need to install any other apps.

Comment: Good suggestion, but seems to be broken for my video stream.

Answer (score 3):

There is some code here

[ali1234/fullscreenhack](https://github.com/ali1234/fullscreenhack)

Which creates a small wrapper library that can be pre-loaded before launching firefox or chrome and it fixes the information about the screen sizes that flash uses, so you get full screen flash on either monitor at the correct full size. It is quite simple to set up

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libx11-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev
git clone git://github.com/ali1234/fullscreenhack.git
cd fullscreenhack
make
env LD_PRELOAD=./libfullscreenhack.so firefox
```

then try a video full screen.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

[Fullscreen Flash Video With Dual Monitors Workarounds | Ubuntu Root](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2011/07/fullscreen-flash-video-with-dual.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar issue which does not answer exactly your question, but still might be helpful for your usecase. When watching fullscren HTML5 videos (e.g. youtube), the video closes by default if you click anywhere. This behavour can be disabled in Firefox by setting `full-screen-api.exit-on-deactivate` to `false` in `about:config`. **Anyhow, this does not effect Flash videos.**

[Html5 video won't stay full screen on second monitor? | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](http://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/927294)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 13.04, this command works for me:

```
sudo sed -i 's/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/_AET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/g' /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend UMPLAYER for youtube videos, also searching, watching and saving features includes.

HD videos and much more.

Would you test features of youtube?

[UMPlayer Available In The WebUpd8 Ubuntu PPA ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/umplayer-available-in-webupd8-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

### [Minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube)[image: Install minitube]

Use this app as a workaround with additional powers of download/save/search as well as NOT using flashplayer you may wish to try.

[image: Minitube]

Shows any resolution windowed or full screen on any screen but as a word of warning - Minitube is not an attempt to emulate Youtube, just a way to screen videos. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred workaround for flash fullscreen multiple monitors issues is [MaximizeFlash](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljjmflmcnaigbhnheldbdbplkbhngnl) extension for Chrome.

It allows the flash video to fill the entire browser window, which can then be put in fullscreen and you can work in another window.

Only downside is that the flash controls are still visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fash to go full screen mod,  drag the **screen you want it to be in**, on the left in "screen display" menu. Just switch the positions of the display icons in this menu. this should work with any browser

Comment: What's a "screen display" menu?

Answer (score 0):

Old but busted:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-multi-monitor-tweaks-full-screen.html.

Maybe people like me are still searching for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My way to solve this problem is by installing Google Chrome for Linux.

1. Install Gdebi (`sudo apt-get install gdebi`)
2. [Download Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
3. Select the right version (for amd64 or i386)
4. Install Google Chrome with Gdebi (or the Ubuntu Software Center)
5. In Chrome Flash is working correctly (the flash plugin in Chrome is newer than the Flash plugin in Firefox, and doesn't contain the bug)
6. Now Full screen flash is working on the correct screen (tested on Ubuntu Mate, should be working for other Ubuntu flavours, Debian or Linux Mint too). For RPM Based distributions use the RPM installer instead of the DEB installer.