# Multi Monitor Fullscreen video problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, error-handling, display-manager

So I have a question, I am somewhat new to Ubuntu and my Current system has a Three monitor setup on it. It's all hooked up and works great, but I wanted to install the disc that came with the monitors, thinking that would give me more functionality controls and help me understand the system. UltraViewSetup1.00.exe and it will try and open it via archive manager then will display this error

```
Archive:  /media/Ultraview Desktop Suite/Ultraview Desktop Suite/UltraViewSetup1.00.exe
[/media/Ultraview Desktop Suite/Ultraview Desktop Suite/UltraViewSetup1.00.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/Ultraview Desktop Suite/Ultraview Desktop Suite/UltraViewSetup1.00.exe or
          /media/Ultraview Desktop Suite/Ultraview Desktop Suite/UltraViewSetup1.00.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/Ultraview Desktop Suite/Ultraview Desktop Suite/UltraViewSetup1.00.exe.ZIP, period.
```

My actual question is every time I full screen a video from another screen it will always go to the far left screen and I want to be able to choose witch screen is full screened if anyone can help me out on what i need to do that would be greatly appriciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't open or install `UltraViewSetup1.00.exe` is because it's a Windows executable file. The `.exe` at the end of the filename tells you it will only work on Windows operating systems.

Most Ubuntu applications will have a `.deb` extension.

As for the fullscreen problem on multiple monitors, this is a bug with Flash. Flash opens the fullscreen video on the primary monitor rather than the one it originated from. This has been [answered already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43755/dual-monitor-youtube-full-screen-help) on AskUbuntu.

I use a similar method as is highlighted in the answer to the linked question. I'm using Opera coupled with the [MediaPlus extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/mediaplus/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help!!! sorry about not looking first BTdub  I am new to Forums and that is a Noobish move apparently!

Comment: It's ok, you'll know for next time. :) Also, please accept the answer if it helped you so people with the same problem can also find a solution!